# NHibernate does not clear SQL Server error text in consecutive exception messages

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate

I'm using this code (simplified) to test some Exception and Error Handling:

```
// All the objects in the collection already exist in the database
// so NHibernate should throw an Exception because of a PK constraint
// violation
foreach (var existingEntity in existingEntities)
{
    // Implementation calls Session.CreateTransaction(), 
    // but the interface returns System.Data.IDbTransaction.
    // This assembly has no references to NHibernate.
    using (var transaction = repo.CreateTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            // Executes a simple insert
            repo.SaveComposite(existingEntity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();

            // Only record the inner-most message
            var innerException = e;
            while (innerException.InnerException != null)
                innerException = innerException.InnerException;

            Errors.Add(new Error(ErrorCode.ExceptionOccurred, innerException.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that each consecutive Exception contains the error text of the previous Exception.

eg.  When trying to insert 3 entities with existing IDs 1, 2 and 3, these are the InnerException messages that are generated:

Item with ID 1:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Example'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Example'. The duplicate key value is
>   (1).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Item with ID 2:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Example'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Example'. The duplicate key value is
>   (1).\r\nViolation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Example'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Example'. The duplicate key value
>   is (2).\r\nThe statement has been terminated.\r\nThe statement has
>   been terminated."

Item with ID 3:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Example'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Example'. The duplicate key value is
>   (1).\r\nViolation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Example'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Example'. The duplicate key value
>   is (2).\r\nViolation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Example'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Example'. The duplicate key value
>   is (3).\r\nThe statement has been terminated.\r\nThe statement has
>   been terminated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Is this a SQL Server or NHibernate problem?  How can I force NHibernate to clear the previous error message?

[EDIT]:  If I set the batch_size to 1 (it's currently using the default batch_size) then the same error message is repeated and nested for each iteration.

The problem also persists after calling Session.Clear().

Comment: do you have some batching size specified in the mapping?

Comment: No.  The mapping just specifies the column/object name mappings and key-relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you encounter an exception you do not want to reuse your ISession.  ISessions should be disposed of after an exception occurs.

I'll also mention that I'm not sure how the errors are duplicated exactly.  You mention specific output but is that being outputted by the following statement?

```
Errors.Add(new Error(ErrorCode.ExceptionOccurred, innerException.Message));
```

If you are logging or outputting each error as it's being added to that "collection" you would get the output you are describing above.  You would want to instead wait until the end of foreach loop to output anything you have added to `Errors`.  You may want to watch the sql being ran as you debug it to verify what I'm saying.

I'll also mention that if you are trying to save entities that may or may not exist you may want to use ISession.Merge instead of what you are currently using.

From the [NHibernate documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/):

> This method copies the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. The method returns the persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved or does not exist in the database, NHibernate will save it and return it as a newly persistent instance. Otherwise, the given instance does not become associated with the session. In most applications with detached objects, you need both methods, SaveOrUpdate() and Merge().

Comment: The error messages were taken directly from the Exception in Debug view.  The piece of code you highlighted does nothing but add the message to an external list.  Also, the code in question will never perform an update or merge.  It's exclusively used for inserts.

Comment: @ilitirit If this is true then it's probably the fact that you are using the same ISession after each error occurs.  Again this is generally not recommended.  You can potentially call `ISession.Clear()` to remove any existing updates related to the `ISession` in question after an error occurs but again this isn't recommended.

Comment: I've tried clearing the Session but it has no effect.  The problem is this code is running on Web Controller and the Session is Created at the start of each Request, Injected into the Repository, and disposed afterwards so I have no control over it.